# Mutually singular signed measures

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be signed measures on $(X, M)$. I want to show that that
$$\nu\perp \mu  \iff |\nu| \perp μ  \iff \nu^+\perp \mu  \text{ and } \nu^-\perp \mu .$$ The definition I have for the mutually singular measures is the following:

Two measures $\mu,  \nu$ are *mutually singular* on $X$ if $X$ can be written as a disjoint union of two measurable sets i.e. $X= E_1\cup E_2$ such that $\mu(A 
\cap E_1) = \nu( A\cap E_2) = 0$ for any measurable set $A$ in $X$. I tried with the Hahn Decomposition theorem. Unfortunately, I am stuck with this problem for a while. Could you provide a little bit of hint? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\nu \perp \mu$. There exist disjoint measurable sets $E_1,E_2$ with union $$X such that $\mu(A \cap E_1)=0$ and $\nu (A \cap E_2)=0$ for all $A$. This implies that $|\nu| (A \cap E_2)=0$ for all $A$ [because $|\nu| (B) =\sup \sum_n |\nu (C_n)|$ where the supremum is over all partitions $(C_n)$ of $B$]. Hence $|\nu| \perp \mu$.

The remaining implications are all immediate from the following: $\nu^ {\pm } \leq |\nu|$ and $|\nu| =\nu ^{+}+\nu ^{+}$.

It is not clear to me as to what definition of $|\nu|$ you are using. I have used the definitition  from Rudin's book.

Comment: The definition I am using for $\mu^{+}$ is the restriction of $\mu $ on $X_{+}$ where  $X_{+}$ denotes the positive set of a Hahn decomposition of $X.$ Similarly, he defined  $\mu^{-}$, then the author defined $|ν|$  the sum  $ν^{+} + ν^{-}$. Thanks  so much.